# Async/Await not working for inserting data inside loop

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I have an array of objects of some records, I want to insert those records inside a loop but it is not working.

req.notifications(array of objects):

```
[ { user_group: 'reporter',
    notification_type: 'email,dashboard',
    parent_id: 1 },
  { user_group: 'assignee',
    notification_type: 'email',
    parent_id: 1 },
  { user_group: 'superadmin',
    notification_type: 'sms,dashboard',
    parent_id: 1 } ]
```

Model function:

```
exports.notificationAdd = async function(req, callback) {
    var notifications = req.notifications; 
    var _err = [];
    await Promise.all(notifications.map(async (notification) => {
        var schemaObj = new NotificationSchema(notification);
        await schemaObj.save(function(err, created){
            if(err){ _err.push(err); }
        });
    }));
    if(_err.length > 0) {
        callback({ code: 400, status: 'error', message: "Unable to add notification", data: _err});
    } else {
        callback({ code: 200, status: 'success', message: 'Notification successfully added!'});
    }
};
```

I am getting the following error:

```
\App\myProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:132
      throw err;
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

I saw the database, only one record is inserted. When I debug the code then I have seen loop is going to next counter without executing the save function inside the loop, only last time it executes the save function.

Thank You.

Comment: I think you're mixing and matching too much.  If you `await` a promise, what it returns is no longer a promise, so I think you're trying to call `Promise.all` on an array of probably ... dunno.  Adding a callback to schemaObj.save will probably cause it to *not* return a Promise anymore, but that will depend on your persistence library.  You also `await` that, though, so even if it does return a Promise you're not passing that promise back up, you're resolving it first.

Comment: Does `save` even return a promise when you pass a callback?

Comment: I am using camintejs as Cross DB ORM so I don't know there is return promise or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `for...of` to resolve a promise inside a loop.

Something like this (not tested):

```
for(let notification of notifications){
  try {
    var schemaObj = new NotificationSchema(notification);
    await schemaObj.save();
  } catch (e) {
    _err.push(err)
  }
}
```

Try not to mix the callback pattern with the promise one

Comment: That's for sequential iteration. Using `Promise.all`+`map` is fine for concurrent execution.

Comment: Instead of using `for` loop, use [async-parallel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-parallel), where in you can also control the concurrency.